# App engine new instance every request

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey-1.0

I'm using Google app engine with Jersey (1.17). I got 0.5-1 request/sec (max).Only one instance run with the automatique scaling (Frontend).
But 1 april goes crazy, every request new instance start. I think that start with the new version 1.9.2.

To resolve it I switch to new instance management and set basic scaling with one instance max.
The problem is :

- non-automatic scaling run on backend
- why new instance start every request

threadsafe and sessions-enabled are activate.

Thanks

Comment: Did this get resolved automatically? The same is happening to me right now. All other sites are fine. For some reason just one spawns instances like crazy unnecessarily. Costing me a small fortune to keep my site alive.

Comment: I use it now and it's not perfect but really better : <instance-class>F1</instance-class>
 <automatic-scaling>
 <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
 <max-idle-instances>1</max-idle-instances>
    <max-concurrent-requests>100</max-concurrent-requests>
 <min-pending-latency>15.0s</min-pending-latency>
 <max-pending-latency>15.0s</max-pending-latency>